# Remap keys in the keyboard for a specific language only in Windows 10

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, autohotkey, language

I wonder how can I remap keys in the keyboard for a specific language only in Windows 10?

I'm using three languages in my OS: English, Hebrew, and Syriac. The problem is that the Syriac layout in Windows isn't intuitive for Semitic linguistics and I want to remap the keys for more intuitive use.

I discovered some remap methods (like Sharpkeys and AutoHotKeys) but all of them were irrelevant because I want to save the layout for English and Hebrew and remap *only* the Syriac layout.

What is the correct way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: AutoHotKey can do it, if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go about it would be to create your own custom keyboard layout.

Assuming you're on windows, you can download [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MSKLC)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134) - but there are other third party software available as well.

After creating your custom layout, install it and choose it under language preferences.